# Stored procedure execution time out problem

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure.When i execute it in query analyzer it takes 47 sec.
So my web application throwing Timeout exception.
Can we do any modification in my code or web.config file instead of doing changes in stored procedure to resolve this problem.

I have following settings in my config file

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
```

My Code is:

```
Dim ds = New DataSet()
        _dbCommand = _database.GetStoredProcCommand("GetDetailsForAll")
        _dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ds = _database.ExecuteDataSet(_dbCommand)
```

here if i add one more line :

```
_dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 120
```

then my problem solved.
so my question is i have set timeout in web.config file. Do i need to add     _dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 120 line in my code also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New answer based on updated question**

The timeout in the connection string property in the .config file is the connection timeout, not the command timeout. The connection timeout is the amount of time to wait for the SQL Server to initially respond to the connection, not the amount of time it takes to perform the query.

If you want to set a command timeout in the config file, you have to code that youself as it is not part of the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

enlarge the timeout in the db-connection-class .., but i would suggest to optimize the SP first !

Comment: Do you mean you are getting a 47second timout from accessing the state? If not, then you probably need to look at the connectionstrings, not the state configuration.

Comment: Where did that comment go? There was a comment giving state configuration settings...